# How to tell which controller threw an exception

Tags: error-handling, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to create an error handling middleware which handles AJAX requests different than page requests. If a specific method in a controller is used for serving up responses to AJAX requests I want to return a JSON response if an exception is thrown. For any failed page requests I'll redirect to a standard error page.

One idea I had to do this was to use a custom attribute. In theory I would then be able to set if we should have JSON or redirect error handling. However, I don't know how I can tell what controller threw the error so I can try to read the custom attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ExceptionOutputMethod OutputMethod { get; private set; }

    public ExceptionHandlerAttribute(ExceptionOutputMethod method)
    {
        OutputMethod = method;
    }
}

public enum ExceptionOutputMethod {
    /// <summary>
    /// For AJAX calls to your API you can return a JSON error object
    /// </summary>
    JSON,

    /// <summary>
    /// For failed page renders use this to redirect to a custom error page
    /// </summary>
    Redirect
};

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ExceptionHandler(ExceptionOutputMethod.Redirect)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("Global handler will redirect to error page");
        return View();
    }

    [ExceptionHandler(ExceptionOutputMethod.JSON)]
    public ExampleObject GetAjaxExample()
    {
        throw new Exception("Create JSON response from global handler");
        return new ExampleObject();
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to tell which controller threw an exception? Alternatively I could find a way to configure all the paths for each type and then do a lookup based on the request. However that sounds like a lot of work to setup and maintain and I would like something that is a little easier for new developers to pickup and use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ExceptionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters) to catch exceptions in MVC actions. Here's a starting point:

```
public class GlobalExceptionCatcher : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly ILogger<GlobalExceptionCatcher> _logger;

    public GlobalExceptionCatcher(
    IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
    IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider,
    ILogger<GlobalExceptionCatcher> logger)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // take some action if needed.
            return;
        }

        var ad = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        var controllerName = ad.ControllerName;

       //go do whatever it is you need to do.
       //you can also set the ExceptionHandled property to "mark as read" :)

    }

}
```

and then in up your startup:

```
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(GlobalExceptionCatcher));
    });
```

If you want a middleware to catch any exception, then, you can use this filter as a utility to add data to your exception middleware that happen in MVC actions. Use the HttpContext.Items property to add info that you want to pick up in your middleware.

But, to make sure your middleware is hit on an exception on the way back make sure you don’t mark the exceptionhandled to true and test properly.

Comment: I was hoping to add my exception handling as the first middleware to give it the best chance catching an exception from any point in the pipeline. However this does look really useful and I'll spend a bit playing with the concept.

Comment: Edited the answer to your follow-up ... hope that helps.

Comment: I was kind of thinking about doing something like this but it would not entirely solve the problem. If you have an exception originate from middleware then it would not be able to tell what controller was contacted as the exception filter would not catch it. The error handler middleware would then not know how to handle it. This might be as good as you can get and I'll have to just have a default in that case.